# predict lme4 for type "response" (binary choices) -- Confidence intervals

Tags: r, confidence-interval, lme4

I ran a mixed effect logistig regression with lme4 (type="response"). Now I used the predict feature and wanted also to determine confidence intervals.

I found this code ( http://glmm.wikidot.com/faq) for predictions, it works, but the CIs are not suitable for binary reponses (my predictions are between 0 and 1, and suddenly the CIs are between -3 and 3. Does anyone know where to adjust this?

```
library(lme4)
library(ggplot2) # Plotting
fm1<- glmer(choice~rating + indi + rating*indi + (1|ID),data=z,family="binomial")
newdat<-data.frame(indi=factor(c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2)), 
rating=factor(1:6), ID=factor(rep(c(1:30), each=12)), choice=0)
newdat$prob<-predict(fm1,newdata=newdat, re.form=NULL, type="response")

mm <- model.matrix(terms(fm1),newdat)
newdat$choice<- predict(fm1,newdat)
## or newdat$choice<- mm %*% fixef(fm1)
pvar1 <- diag(mm %*% tcrossprod(vcov(fm1),mm))
tvar1 <- pvar1+VarCorr(fm1)$ID[1]  ## must be adapted        
tvar1 <- 
  newdat <- data.frame(
   newdat
   , plo = newdat$choice-2*sqrt(pvar1)
, phi = newdat$choice+2*sqrt(pvar1)
, tlo = newdat$choice-2*sqrt(tvar1)
, thi = newdat$choice+2*sqrt(tvar1)
)
#plot confidence
g0 <- ggplot(newdat, aes(x=rating, y=choice, colour=indi))+geom_point()
g0 + geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = plo, ymax = phi))+
opts(title="CI based on fixed-effects uncertainty ONLY")
#plot prediction
g0 + geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = tlo, ymax = thi))+
opts(title="CI based on FE uncertainty + RE variance")
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't see any logistic regression in your code.

Comment: sorry, I will change the code according to my paradigm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the inverse-link function, `plogis()` in this case:

```
 newdat <- transform(newdat,
        plo = plogis(plo),
        phi = plogis(phi),
        tlo = plogis(tlo),
        thi = plogis(thi))
```

More generally if you have fitted a model `gm1` the inverse-link function will be stored in `gm1@resp$family$linkinv` (although mucking around with the internals of an object like this is not guaranteed to remain compatible with future versions).